# What should be the design/Pattern for adding/deleting some piece of Code in the existing one

Tags: java, design-patterns

I got a requirement in **JAVA PROJECT** which contains a massive *adding* and *deleting* source codes from the existing working copy. There is no other way out. As per design contract, I must not modify the source code , so I thought of inherit the features, ***but is it the only way to do it?*** Because it is around 2000+ files changes and each file inheritance is not possible because of Access Specifiers and finals in JAVA.

EXAMPLE:
Consider a File named MenuManager.java is having a method which adds 10 Menus in the MenuBar.Now as per my requirement I need to remove 5 menus from the existing one and add newly defined(by me) 3 Menus into the same MenuBar.
So easiest option is override the method but what if this type of features changes is there for the entire source code

Comment: why close vote , when I am expecting a solution from Design perspective

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you deleting source file?  Like *.java?    Or are you trying to use an existing project as a library?

Comment: I want to modify the source files , for example , I have a piece of code which adds 10Menus on the MenuBar, now I need to remove 5 menus from the MenuBar and add newly defined 3 new Menues through the existing source code

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems that:

- the current source code *does not fulfill* your requirements
- you *can't change* or easily extend the source code

If these are hard facts, you're faced with a difficult situation. One way forward is to create a separate architecture that *wraps* the existing functionality when it makes sense to use it, or write new code for when it's hard to reuse. In this way, you treat the existing code as an *external library* that you use when it makes sense. Some patterns that come to mind are *bridge* and *adapter*. Inheritance is normally not a good way forward because it couples the extensions (subclasses) too tightly with the superclasses.

So, given your example:

> Consider a File named MenuManager.java is having a method which adds 10 Menus in the MenuBar.Now as per my requirement I need to remove 5 menus from the existing one and add newly defined(by me) 3 Menus into the same MenuBar.

You could do it like this (this is just the idea, unrelated to any libraries like Swing):

```
// MyMenuManager.java <-- your new class

// method that adds menu items
public void addItems(Menu menu) {
  new MenuManager().addItems(menu); // calls the old functionality
  // adapt the menu
  removeObsoleteItems(menu);
  addNewItems(menu);
}
```

This would be your first version, ideally you'd evolve this to not depend on the old code anymore, *assuming* your ultimate goal is to replace the old application (which, given your constraints, seems reasonable).

Other more involved patterns can also be used, like an [anti-corruption layer](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/07/07/domain-driven-design-anti-corruption-layer/).

Answer (score 0):

If the code was developed with a plugin architecture in mind, you would be able to enable and disable the features you want and don't want, either as part of the build process or part of run time. The problem is that it sounds like the original source was not designed to do this.

Inheritance is one option if it fits. You might be able to override some calls to make them do more of what you want.

In the case of your example, you might be able to modify the components after they have been added:

```
    final JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setSize(300, 300);
            f.setJMenuBar(menubar);
            menubar.add(new JMenu("Magic"));
            menubar.add(new JMenu("Stain"));
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < menubar.getMenuCount(); i++)
            {
                JMenu item = menubar.getMenu(i);
                if(item != null && "Magic".equals(item.getText()))
                {
                    menubar.remove(i);
                    i--;
                    menubar.doLayout();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

You would obviously want to wrap this sort of code to make it easy for you to remove certain elements from a menu bar.

The hardest thing about your question is you have polar opposite requirements. "**I must not modify the source code**" and "**massive adding and deleting source**"

It sounds like you are wanting to fork the project to go off in a different direction.